# SharePoint Online Pages are loading 2 times on Edge

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-edge, sharepoint-online

On a SharePoint Online, all the pages are loading 2 times on Microsoft Edge. On Chrome, it's fine. The is loaded a first time and then a second load is done.

It happens for on all sites of this tenant. Unfortunately, I don't have all the history of this tenant.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Ghislain

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? Does the issue happen in other tenant? Have you tried in Edge InPrivate window to see if the issue still persists? If possible, you can provide a link which can reproduce the issue so that we can have a test.

Comment: Thanks for your message.
I don't know how, but now it's solved.